# Condition establishing inclusion of singular surface inside multi-dimensional contour

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, surfaces

Consider the parametrization of a surface $\gamma(t,s)=(t+i\kappa_1(t,s),s+i\kappa_2(t,s))$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$, and let

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{I}=\int dt ds \ \text{det}(\mathbb{J}\gamma)\frac{1}{f(\gamma(t,s))}
\end{equation}
be the integral of a complex function along the surface. Assume that the complex function $f(z), \ z=(z_1,z_2)$, $z_1,z_2\in\mathbb{C}$ has zeros on a bounded, connected surface which has no purely real points, denoted by $\mathcal{S}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}^2\ | \ f(z)=0, \ \mathcal{I}\text{m}(z)\neq 0\}$. We can say that the surface is included in the contour $\gamma$ if $\mathcal{S}$ lies in between the real plane and the surface parametrized by $\gamma$.

What is the condition, preferably expressed in terms of $f$ which, for a given surface $\gamma$, establishes that the surface $\mathcal{S}$ is or isn't included in the contour $\gamma$?

Comment: You shouldn't call this a complex surface. At first glance I thought $t,s\in\Bbb C$. But your surface is just a real surface sitting in $\Bbb C^2$. Why should we expect this integral to converge? What do we know about $\kappa_1,\kappa_2$?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know the distinction! I'm less interested in the integration per se and its convergence and more in understanding if a condition for the inclusion of the singular surface can be found, but probably the problem is badly formulated. When integrating a function $f(z)$ on a contour $\gamma$, we can say wether a point $z^*$ is contained in the contour, for example by comparing the imaginary part of the parametrized contour when its real part coincides with the imaginary part of $z^*$. I'm trying to find a similar setup and a similar condition for a higher dimensional case.